# Highlight current page on main menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use javascript / jQuery to highlight the current pages list item on my main menu. I am new to scripting and can't work out what the problem is.
Here is the code i've been trying with.

```
<ul id="#mainMenu">
    <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#mainMenu li a').on('click', function(){
    $('li a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I presume you've added the extra CSS for the elements with the class of `active`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're happy to add the class to the menu based on the current URL in oppose to using the `.click` function then I have a solution for you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[href*='" + location.pathname + "']").addClass("active");
});
```

On page load. This compares all the anchor tags on the page to the current URL. And if they match. Adds the class of `.active` to the element.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add to the accepted answer by Jay. Sometimes your URL may be 'posts' for a menu item and 'posts/create' for another one. So code from accepted answer will highlight both. To avoid that, do the following: use window.location.href instead of location.pathname and remove * after href:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[href='" + window.location.href + "']").addClass("active");
});
```